# Appsflyer sending uninstall event

Tags: java, android, appsflyer

Appsflyer keeps showing integration with GCM and not firebase, Could someone help me with how to capture uninstall event with appsflyer?

Comment: Appsflyer released new version 4.7.0 that contains firebase intergration. It should be similar to GCM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Maxim commented, AppsFlyer released new SDK version for Android (4.7.0) - which includes Firebase support for Uninstall Tracking.
Please refer to AppsFlyer Docs, and follow the instructions here: https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/208004986-Android-Uninstall-Tracking

If you're still having issues, I'd be happy to help.

Comment: Thanks a ton! It's just the documentation I was looking for. I contacted Appsflyer but they kept directing me to their older documentation!